# Display a list of random terms from custom taxonomy with shortcode

Tags: functions, categories, custom-taxonomy, shortcode, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I try to output a list of terms from my custom taxonomy.
I am almost sure I was using this code snippet before, but somehow WP throws errors:

- shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array
- array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array
- usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

```
/* Show Custom Taxonomy Terms */

function these_rand_tax1() {
$max = 8; //number of categories to display
$taxonomy = 'baumaschinen_cat';
$terms = get_terms('taxonomy='.$taxonomy.'&orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0');


// Random order
shuffle($terms);


// Get first $max items
$terms = array_slice($terms, 0, $max);


// Sort by name
usort($terms, function($a, $b){
  return strcasecmp($a->name, $b->name);
});


// Echo random terms sorted alphabetically
if ($terms) {
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<p><a href="' .get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ) . '" title="' .  sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a></p> ';
  }
}
}


add_shortcode('random_taxonomies','these_rand_tax1');
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

How can I achieve to get a random list from my custom taxonomy terms?

Comment: it looks like you're assuming `get_terms` returned results, and didn't handle the failure case for when nothing was found or when it was given bad arguments, there's nothing in the code in your question to handle if it returned a `WP_Error` object. Also I notice you're passing arguments as a string not an array, is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Also, your shortcode uses `echo` to output directly to the browser, this is very very bad and will break a lot of things, e.g it the shortcode willl not appear in the correct order, won't support nesting, and will break the REST API/RSS/XMLRPC etc. Shortcode functions must return their HTML, not output it directly.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your inputs. As i am not familiar with PHP, I tried to do my best by researching and testing different code puzzles.

Could you give me an example how this shortcode function should look like? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `get_terms` returns object not array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function these_rand_tax1()
{
    $max = 8; //number of categories to display
    $taxonomy = 'baumaschinen_cat';
    $terms = get_terms('taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0');
    $terms = (array)$terms;

    // Random order
    shuffle($terms);


    // Get first $max items
    $terms = array_slice($terms, 0, $max);


    // Sort by name
    usort($terms, function ($a, $b)
    {
        return strcasecmp($a->name, $b->name);
    });


    // Echo random terms sorted alphabetically
    if ($terms)
    {
        foreach ($terms as $term)
        {
            echo '<p><a href="' . get_term_link($term['slug'], $taxonomy) . '" title="' .  sprintf(__(" View all posts in %s"), $term['name']) . '" ' . '>' . $term['name'] . '</a></p> ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws me an error for this line:

`echo '<p><a href="' . get_term_link($term, $taxonomy) . '" title="' .  sprintf(__(" View all posts in %s"), $term->name) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name . '</a></p> ';`

The error:
`Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string`

Comment: i have updated the same line, please check.